# Is there software to calculate/plot decomposed rotation curves from observational data (FITS, etc)?

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, dark-matter, software, galaxy-rotation-curve

I have observation data of galaxies (in FITS format). From the FITS data, I want to calculate & plot the decomposed rotation curves as pictured below. Is there a software package that will do that (preferably in Python)?

Here's an example of a working FITS file (use ngc2403.fits):
https://editeodoro.github.io/Bbarolo/downloads/examples/

Context: I'm interested in finding the radial mass distribution of the dark matter in each galaxy. If there is already a database or catalog of this, then telling me that would be even better.

[Image from: Roos, Matts. (2010). Dark Matter: The evidence from astronomy, astrophysics and cosmology. [arXiv:1001.0316]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0316)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "observation data"?

Comment: @tom10 Thanks, but I think `astropy.io.fits` only loads the FITS data. I don't think astropy has a function that turns the data into decomposed rotation curves (which is what I want).

Comment: @ProfRob By "observation data", I mean FITS files from the telescopes observing the galaxies. In other words, it's the "picture" taken by the telescope. Here's some sample FITS files: https://esahubble.org/projects/fits_liberator/m31data/

Comment: Put exactly what data you have and what you want to do with it into your question.

Comment: Can you actually be specific? Rotation curves, decompositions, kinematic models, etc. are the main focus of my research, so I expect I know the answer, but you still haven't said what kind of data you have, so the best answer I have is still "it depends".

Comment: @KyleOman and ProfRob I've edited the post to include a link to a working FITS file (ngc403.fits)

Comment: Ok, well you're linking it from the 3dbarolo pages, so I guess you know about that package. That will plot the rotation curve, and calculate inclination and "asymmetric drift" (more correctly pressure support) corrections. You can use the 3db gas surface density profile to calculate the gas part of the decomposition. For the stellar part you need some photometry, preferably at 3.6 microns. The DM part is the remainder. You may wish to fit it with a profile (and possibly also leave the stellar M/L somewhat free). Usually all these steps are a DIY job, not something there's a package for...

Comment: You may check the SPARC (Lelli, McGaugh & Schombert) database for a collection of galaxies with the decompositions already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at the Spitzer Photometry and Accurate Rotation Curves (SPARC) database of Lelli, McGaugh and Schombert (2016): http://astroweb.cwru.edu/SPARC/ The Li et al. (2020) halo fits listed on the same page may also be of interest.

From a fits file like the one you linked, once you've extracted the rotation curve (your example file is one of the examples from 3DBarolo, which will do this - follow the instructions in its documentation...), the rest of what you want is not something standardised in some typical package, it's more of a DIY job.